# Need help hiding/showing custom navBar IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uigesturerecognizer

I need help showing and hiding my custom navigation bar that is not linked with a navigation controller. I have initialized my nav bar and `UITapGestureRecognizer` in `viewWillAppear` and want to have the gesture selector to show and hide the nav bar. I have tried numerous `navigationController` functions but since I have not embedded one they do not seem to work:

```
navigationController?.barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer
// OR
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
// OR
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

I have seen that the:

```
navigationBar.hidden = true    //OR FALSE
```

can change the initial appearance of the navBar, but it cannot toggle show/hide like i need it to. Basically it just needs to mimic the apple Photos app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just use a navigation controller?

Comment: Halfway through writing this I realized I should just have another, but I already have 2 and its kind of annoying linking around to send objects from one controller to another. Prob more work not having it though, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go is to create an **IBAction** for your custom navigation bar. In this **IBAction** you set

```
navigationBar.hidden = true
```

or

```
navigationBar.hidden = false
```

depending on the current **hidden** state

**Or if you create your elements programmatically**, you can try an approach using **Target** and **Event** for your `UIGestureRecognizer`.

First you add a **Target** to your element:

```
gestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

In action parameter of `.addTarget`, you set the method name that should be called.

Then write the method where you alter the **hidden** state:

```
func pressed(sender: UIGestureRecognizer!) {
    if navigationBar.hidden = true {
        navigationBar.hidden = false}
    else{
        navigationBar.hidden = true}
}
```

Comment: This does seem like it could work but I have created my navigation bar in code so I don't really have anything physical to create the outlet with?

Comment: @bme003 Ok, then you use your UIGestureRecognizer to catch the tap. I edited the answer.

Comment: @bme003 please mark the answer somehow if you find it helpful

Comment: Sorry this took so long to respond, been out of the country for a week.